# how can i count the elements so i can use the value later?

Tags: cypress

Html:

```
<tbody class="ant-table-tbody">
   <tr class="ant-table-row"> 1 </tr>
  <tr class="ant-table-row"> 2 </tr>
        ...
  <tr class="ant-table-row"> n </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
let count = cy.get('.ant-table-tbody').find('.ant-table-row')
if (count >= 0) {
   cy.log(`There are ${count} elements`)  
} else {
   cy.log('There are no elements')
}
```

When I get `.ant-table-tbody` element I need to count `.ant-table-row` elements. If count more than  '0' cy.log count of elements, if '0' element should cy.log - No elements.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think you ask to know when there's zero rows as well as > 0, so

```js
cy.get('.ant-table-tbody')
.then($tbody => {
  const count = $tbody.find('.ant-table-row').length // jquery find won't fail
  if (count > 0) {
    cy.log(`There are ${count} elements`)  
  } else {
    cy.log('There are no elements')
  }
})
```

If zero rows are not possible, other answers are simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method as your question last July, using an alias

```js
cy.get('.ant-table-tbody')
  .find('.ant-table-row')
  .its('length')
  .as('rowCount')

cy.get('@rowCount')
  .then(count => {
    if (count) {
      cy.log(`There are ${count} elements`) 
    ...
  })
```

or directly after the find

```js
cy.get('.ant-table-tbody')
  .find('.ant-table-row')
  .its('length')
  .then(count => {
    if (count) {   // not count >= 0, because 0 means no elements
      cy.log(`There are ${count} elements`) 
    ...
  })
```

All code using `count` must be inside a `.then()`

Comment: Can I use rowCount in other tests?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an greater than 0 assertion and add custom log message like this:

```js
cy.get('.ant-table-tbody')
  .find('.ant-table-row')
  .its('length')
  .should('be.gt', 0, 'The element count is greater than 0')
```

Or, if you want to assert the count to be greater than and equal to 0, you can

```js
cy.get('.ant-table-tbody')
  .find('.ant-table-row')
  .its('length')
  .should('be.gte', 0, 'The number of elements is greater and equal to 0')
```

Comment: But what to do when zero rows? I don't understand.

Comment: Then the assertion will fail.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad

Comment: @Jumaane Yes that's true. I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I mean, it's ok - I should know that there's some rows on the page if I want to test them, right?